# Boot, OAuth2, Zuul Proxy and Versions

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

So, i've added in Zuul and to get the proxy working realised i needs to add in 'spring-cloud-security' which i did:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The trouble is that as soon as i do this i get this exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancedOauth2RestTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/security/oauth2/client/  OAuth2LoadBalancerClientAutoConfiguration$LoadBalancedOauth2RestTemplateConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of typ[org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

if i do make a bean i get this exception (i'm specifying the resource server info outside of props/yml):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: userInfoRestTemplate,loadBalancedOauth2RestTemplate
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I've been through this previous post:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/73

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE. I've tried (form the above posting) adding in to dep management:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.M3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but to no avail.

I expect this is a 'versions' issue; what is the most recent set of libs & versions to use? I've been through the 'oauth2-vanilla-ui' sample in the AngularJS/Security tutorial. Is it because i'm not using props in the resource file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i managed to figure it out. So i upped the version of 'spring-cloud-security' to '1.1.0.M4' as I noticed some of the autoconf had changed. Also, i left my 'OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails' as a bean and added an 'OAuth2RestTemplate' bean but, crucially, marked it as primary:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "platformClientRestTemplate")
public OAuth2RestTemplate clientRestTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(platformOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails(), oauth2ClientContext);
}
```

this means the problem of multiple RestTemplates goes away (and ensures the rest template i want gets used).

This means i'm using (for anyone with version issues):

Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE
spring-cloud-security 1.1.0.M4
spring-cloud-starter-zuul 1.1.0.M3